# Why does the compiler not optimize away interrupt code?

Tags: c, optimization, interrupt, cortex-m

I recently ran into a problem with a variable only being modified in an interrupt handler. The variable itself was not declared volatile so at higher levels of optimization the compiler broke the code. However, the compiler is smart enough to compile the interrupt code because the interrupt still fires.

So here are my questions:

1. If the compiler is smart enough to compile the interrupt code, why is it not smart enough to realize that variables are changed inside that interrupt?
2. At higher levels of optimization, functions that aren't called get optimized out. Since no code calls the interrupt handler it should get optimized away. What causes the compiler to compile the interrupt code anyway?

Comment: Post your code and possibly the relevant disassembly

Comment: What compiler are you using (is it a recent version of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/))? What are the optimization flags? What is the target platform and processor? And why don't you use `volatile` (you really should in your case)?

Comment: Maybe because it is referenced when you load the vectored interrupt controller with the address?   If the address of the handler is referenced, then the compiler will assume that it may be called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The language execution model says that an ordinary (non-volatile) variable cannot be changed by "external forces". I.e. if your code flow does not explicitly change the variable, then from that code flow's point of view the variable cannot possibly change. (Besides what's defined by C11 for multithreaded execution). You have to manually "designate" variables that can be changed by interrupt handlers.

   This is one of the main factors that enables efficient optimizations of C code. It cannot be eliminated without making a significant negative impact on the performance of C programs.
2. Firstly, compilers don't usually optimize away functions with external linkage. Is your interrupt handler declared with external linkage?

   Secondly, the decision to optimize out a function or keep it is not really based on whether the function is *called* or not. It is based on whether the corresponding symbol is *referenced* in your program in any way. Non-referenced symbols are removed, while the referenced ones are kept. There are other ways to reference a function symbol besides calling it. For example, taking address of a function also counts as a reference to function symbol. Functions whose addresses are taken anywhere in the program are never optimized away.

   Your interrupt vector entry gets initialized somehow at program startup, which normally involves taking address of the handler function. That is already sufficient to protect this function from being optimized out.

Comment: I am using an stm32 processor and the manufacturer's support library has obscured away many of the interrupt linking details. I know that I need to write `TIM4_IRQHandler` for example somewhere in my code and the linker places this handler at the correct spot in the vector section. The compiler keeps the function because the linker placed the address of `TIM4_IRQHandler` in the vector section. This is what I'm supposing is happening.

Comment: @thndrwrks: If your implementation provides some implicit "under the hood" functionality that makes sure that your `TIM4_IRQHandler` gets placed into the proper location in the interrupt vector, then it is more than likely that the very same functionality also takes all necessary steps to prevent `TIM4_IRQHandler` from being optimized away.

Comment: That is indeed what is happening.  Taking the address of the handler for the VIC means that the compiler assumes that it can be called.